# Getting time of Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library pop on Windows Machine

Tags: windows

Is it possible to get the time of a Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library pop on Windows Machine?

It appears that the error only gets logged in event log when you click Abort on the pop up.

However, this is not the time that the actual problem occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not posssible.  It appears that the only way is to attach a debugger to the process.